# WCF Impersonation not denying file system access rights

Tags: c#, wcf, filesystems, impersonation, wshttpbinding

I can't get a self-hosted WCF application to respect server side impersonation for file system access rights.

When I run the service (I can connect without issues) I am able to access the file system where I shouldn't be able to, in this case CreateDirectory().  When the client calls the service, I can see it hitting the server, but it isn't denied access to the file system and still creates a directory in the restricted folder.

I have denied access rights to the folder of the current user and have tried creating a directory when the server is launching from the main thread and it fails with Access Denied. Should be noted then when I call WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name it shows up with the same Name for both instances.

I have included the endpoints for the setup configs for the both the server and client side connections below.

Service Contract Code:

```
public string Ping()
    {
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity callerWindowsIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
        using (callerWindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
        {
            DirectoryInfo test = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\NoPermisionFolder\Test");

            string returnMe = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + " " + test.ToString();

            return returnMe;
        }
    }
```

Server Code:

```
// First procedure:
// create a WSHttpBinding that uses Windows credentials and message security
WSHttpBinding myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;

// 2nd Procedure:
// Use the binding in a service
// Create the Type instances for later use and the URI for 
// the base address.
Type contractType = typeof(ITest);
Type serviceType = typeof(Test);
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://address:port/");

// Create the ServiceHost and add an endpoint, then start
// the service.
ServiceHost myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddress);
myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contractType, myBinding, "");

//enable metadata
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

myServiceHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Listening");
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to close the service");
Console.ReadLine();
myServiceHost.Close();
```

Client Code:

```
string address = "http://address:port/";
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = 
MessageCredentialType.Windows;

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(address), 
EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("host/computerAddress"));

TestClient client = new TestClient(binding, endpointAddress);//"WSHttpBinding_ITest");
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
client.Open();

string test = client.Ping();

client.Close();

Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to close the service");
Console.ReadLine();
```